# Find all vertices in an undirected graph that belong to any cycle

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, depth-first-search

Is there a way to find all vertices that are a part of a simple cycle in a graph in linear time?

I found a way to do it in O(|V|(|V|+|E|)) time but was wondering if there is a way to do it faster?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7216/find-the-simple-cycles-in-a-directed-graph)?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're asking for. Are you given a simple cycle and must find the vertices on it? How is that cycle specified? Are you given a graph, and must filter out any vertices not in some cycle somewhere?

Comment: given a graph G=(V,E), find a group of vertices U so that every vertex u that belongs to U is a vertex on a simple cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have the answer.
while processing DFS, for every vertex v calculate low(v) (explained below). then running DFS once again and check for every vertex v:

> if low(v) != d(v) (where d(v) is the distance from the DFS tree root)
>
> > vertex v is a part of a simple cycle.

*low(v) = min ( d(v),d(u),low(w)) where (v,u) is a back edge and w is a child of v in the DFS tree. calculated in O(|V|+|E|) time.

Answer (score 11):

What you want to do is remove all of the [bridges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29) (i.e. edges that disconnect a component when removed). The Wikipedia article gives two algorithms for finding all of the bridges — [Tarjan's algorithm](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1974/29303.html) and [Schmidt's algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0700) — both of which are linear-time.

Once all the bridges are gone, each node is either isolated (has degree 0) or is part of a cycle. Throw out the lonely nodes, and what's left is the nodes you want.

Comment: IIUC, Tarjan's and Schmidt's algorithms work on undirected graphs, but do not apply to directed graphs — in fact the whole notion of a "bridge" might not apply to a directed graph — is that right? So this answer assumes that OP is looking for cycles in an undirected graph. What would be the answer if OP's graph was a directed graph?

Answer (score 3):

Using DFS (Depth First Search), you can do in O(|V|+|E|) time. while implementing the DFS just keep the record of the vertives you had been tracking with their parent node as soon as you find child node same as parent node(meaning the completion of cycle) you can declare all  the nodes from that parent till the last child as the part of some simple cycle.

Comment below if you need more explanation.

Comment: This isn't a **simple cycle**, this is just a **cycle**. Simple cycle should not contain any other cycle.

Comment: This was the algorithm I had in mind but I think that if very time I find a vertex that have been visited track all its predecessors, I can have |V| circles (a circle that's part of a circle that is part of a circle etc.) and for each one O(|V|) time for this backtrack. which sums to O(|V|(|V|+|E|))

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: "Simple cycle" usually means a cycle in which no vertex appears more than once.  The standard term for what you described is "induced cycle".

Answer (score 0):

I like Bhavya's answer: but it'll help if I elaborate on it.

Usually if you do DFS you have a visited array that holds either visited/not-visited state.

Now have

```
int visited[N];//N is the number of nodes/vertices in graph
```

Let

```
visited[i] =-1 if i-th vertex is not yet visited
visited[i] = 0 if i-th vertex is being processed
visited[i] = 1 if processing of i-th vertex is done
```

This way if you encounter a vertex along dfs with visited value 0, it means you have a cycle.To find vertices on cycle, use a predecessor array to store previous vertex in path.